# Magento 2 - Database values to push in production using Git

Tags: magento2, database, git, github

I want to move system Configuration values and values stored in database to production server using Git.

Can anyone let me know how can I push Admin Changes to Production using Git.

Is it possible through Git?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `app:config:dump` command. This will generate system specific, configuration specific, sensitive configuration settings in config.php.
then you can commit this config.php file on the server
Then using `app:config:import` command you can update your configuration once you update these files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible remove these values via git from the database,
You have to direct changes in the database.

You just add the values from the code like in the `config.xml` through git.